How to specify and confirm which version of node Rails app uses?
We'v got 2 versions of node installed on linode server, one for root is 18 (/usr/bin/node) and for user deploy it's 14 (/home/deploy/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin/node). We want to use 14, we have it specificed in .nvmrc file and also in package.json as like
"engines": {
  "node": "14.x"
}

but when we try to debug it on server in the rails view like:
%p
 Node Version:
 = `node -v`

It shows version 18.
The app is deployed with capistrano when user is deploy so I'v expected same user is used to run rails app ?
